# compare value with all the fields of a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, search

I ahve a table called info_acc (id,state,country,zip) now i need to compare a set of keywords with al the fileds of this table say value is Alaska I need to compare this with id,state,country,zip and in match with any filed then row(s) will be selected. How can I do this with efficient way? Thanks

Comment: use `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following article:

[Using MySQL Full-text Searching](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304)

or use stackoverflow:

[How to implement a Keyword Search in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759580/how-to-implement-a-keyword-search-in-mysql)

[mysql keyword search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548960/mysql-keyword-search)